# Manipulação de Middleware

Tags: javascript, express.js

Estou tentando fazer a seguinte manipulação no ExpressJS.

Eu peguei um projeto MEAN Stack e a pessoa que estava desenvolvendo saiu e eu estou só dando continuidade. Porém agora me deparei com a seguinte situação:

Quando faço 2 solicitações no mongoDB para listar cliente e listar as regiões separados ele só executa ou um ou outro.

Segue o código abaixo (a função `verificaAutenticao` seria a chamada padrão req,res,next):

```
module.exports = function(app)
{
 var controller = app.controllers.maps.cliente;

 app.route('clientes')
    .get(verificaAutenticacao, controller.listaClientes, 
       controller.listaRegionais);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vou quebrar o seu código em algumas partes pra você entender o que está acontecendo:

```
app.route('clientes').get()
```

Você cria uma rota `/clientes` que responde ao um `HTTP GET Request`. Essa rota, quando for acionada (por exemplo, entrando em http://enderecodoservidor.com/clientes no browser), vai engatilhar todos os *middlewares* dentro dessa função **em ordem**:

1. `verificaAutenticacao`
2. `listaClientes`
3. `listaRegionais`

O primeiro *middleware* (`verificaAutenticacao`) é uma função com a seguinte assinatura:

```
function(req, res, next){
// ... executa código, podendo manipular os objetos req e res
next();
}
```

A chamada do método `next`, faz com que os objetos `req` e `res` sejam passados para a próxima função com mesma assinatura (*middleware*) nos argumentos. Nesse caso, a função `listaClientes`.

Essa função, por sua vez, é também um *middleware*, e ao final dela, caso tudo ocorra como esperado, deve haver também uma chamada ao método `next`; sinalizando que a próxima função na "corrente de *middlewares*" (nesse caso, `listaRegionais`), deve ser chamada, com os mesmos objetos `req` e `res`.

O erro está em algum momento nessa corrente/cadeia de chamadas.

Caso, por exemplo, o primeiro *middleware* não verifique a autenticação como sendo válida, é perfeitamente plausível criar um código para retornar uma *response* prematura (um erro 400, por exemplo). Nesse caso, o restante dos *middlewares* **não seriam levados em consideração**.

exemplo:

```
function verificaAutenticacao(req, res, next){
    if(req.auth.login === 'loginCorreto' && req.auth.password === 'senhaCorreta'){
        next(); // nesse caso, pode passar pro próximo middleware
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(400); // quebra a corrente, e acaba por aqui.
    }
}
```

Para maiores dúvidas, verificar a [página que fala sobre os middlewares](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) na documentação original.

Acredito que vale a pena você criar um *middleware* próprio para um aprendizado mais profundo.